# GIMP - how to view the DICOM header of DICOM images?

Tags: gimp, metadata

I can open a DICOM image file using GIMP but unfortunately I cannot find a way to view it's DICOM header. I have tried the "Image -> View Metadata" with no avail (I can see there only the Exif, XMP and IPTC metadata).

My GIMP version is 2.10.2.

Comment: I don't think anyone has added this yet - such features are usually added by people who need them, so maybe you want to contribute this to GIMP?

Comment: In release notes of GIMP 2.10 there is a statement: "Metadata viewing and editing for Exif, XMP, IPTC, and DICOM." But I can't find this feature when I open DICOM files.

Comment: Ah, you want to see the actual data - I got the impression that you somehow wanted to see the raw header data from within GIMP.

Comment: I want to see the DICOM tags and values, like "Patient ID", "Study Instance UID", "Referring physician" and others.